# How to prevent joomla empty modules from being rendered, even returning false?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, module, templates, module-display

How to prevent Joomla empty modules from being rendered?
To achieve this-

I have tried by returning false from module's entry file if there is no output.
I have written following code in modules entry file eg mod_xyx.php

```
// Hide mod when no output.
if ( @no_output)
{
    return ;
}
```

It works for Joomla's default template but doesn't work for some template.

Comment: I also tried by ---  return false;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent empty modules from being rendered?](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4215/how-to-prevent-empty-modules-from-being-rendered)

Answer (score 1):

If you are 100% sure that your module output is empty, then your template may be adding a **chrome** to the module.

You can check how the **JModuleHelper::renderModule** generates the module output and (optionally) calls the template chrome.

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/module/helper.php#L176

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this in the past, and your answer is likely in your template files...you'll probably see that its checking if there is a *count* of modules - something like this from Protostar:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('position-8')) : ?>
<!-- Begin Sidebar -->
<div id="sidebar" class="span3">
    <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-8" style="xhtml" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

It doesn't consider whether there is output or not, so renders the module position regardless of what is/isn't rendered.